# Случайная картинка в делфи

Tags: delphi

Вроде всё просто, но почему-то проблема с типами. Есть папка img/ там хранятся 4 файла вида img_*.jpg. При нажатии на кнопку, изображение выбирается случайно.
Вот код:

```
procedure TProForm.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
v:integer;
begin
v:=Random(4)+1;
image1.Picture:='img/img_'+v+'.jpg';
end;
```

Ошибка:
[Pascal Error] Unit2.pas(44): E2010 Incompatible types: 'TPicture' and 'Integer'
[Pascal Error] Unit2.pas(45): E2010 Incompatible types: 'string' and 'TPicture'

В чём проблема и как больше не допускать таких ошибок? Какой тип задать для переменной v? Чтоб не было проблем?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно так

```
Image1.Picture.LoadFromFile('img_'+ IntToStr(v)+'.jpg');
```

А для загрузки jpg файлов в uses-ах надо добавить модуль jpeg

Answer (score 3):

Используйте IntToStr(), а то у вас получается, что  строке присваивается числовое значение:

```
img:='img_'+ IntToStr(v)+'.jpg';
```

Comment: Плюс, как видно из лога, image1.Picture - это не строка.

Comment: Обновил шапку. Проблема не решена полностью.

Answer (score 0):

```
Uses ... Jpeg;

Begin
Randomize;    
image1.Picture.loadFromFile('img/img_'+IntToStr(Random(4)+1)+'.jpg');
end;
```